# Statement expected, found BAD_CHARACTER

Tags: python, pycharm

Скопировал пример с интернета, Pycharm выдает ошибку: "Statement expected, found BAD_CHARACTER". В чем может быть проблема?

```
 class Person:
        def __init__(self, name, age):
            self.__name = name    # устанавливаем имя
            self.__age = age      # устанавливаем возраст
     
        def set_age(self, age):
            if age in range(1, 100):
                self.__age = age
            else:
                print("Недопустимый возраст")
     
        def get_age(self):
            return self.__age
             
        def get_name(self):
            return self.__name
     
        def display_info(self):
            print("Имя:", self.__name, "\tВозраст:", self.__age)
             
    tom = Person("Tom", 23)
     
    tom.__age = 43              # Атрибут age не изменится
    tom.display_info()          # Имя: Tom  Возраст: 23
    tom.set_age(-3486)          # Недопустимый возраст
    tom.set_age(25)
    tom.display_info()          # Имя: Tom  Возраст: 25
```

Comment: В каком месте ругается? Скопировал ваш пример и pycharm не жаловался (правда он отступы сделал правильные). Проследите, чтобы отступы были у вас по 4 пробела

Comment: С пробелами проблемы были, уже решил проблему

Comment: А у вас в начале файла есть строка `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`?

Comment: @gil9red, такой строки нет

Comment: Добавьте и попробуйте ваш код из вопроса. Возможно в этом была проблема

Comment: @gil9red, спасибо помогло

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендации:

- Сделать единые отступы (4 пробела)
- Добавить в начало файла строку: `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Код:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.__name = name  # устанавливаем имя
        self.__age = age  # устанавливаем возраст

    def set_age(self, age):
        if age in range(1, 100):
            self.__age = age
        else:
            print("Недопустимый возраст")

    def get_age(self):
        return self.__age

    def get_name(self):
        return self.__name

    def display_info(self):
        print("Имя:", self.__name, "\tВозраст:", self.__age)


tom = Person("Tom", 23)

tom.__age = 43  # Атрибут age не изменится
tom.display_info()  # Имя: Tom  Возраст: 23
tom.set_age(-3486)  # Недопустимый возраст
tom.set_age(25)
tom.display_info()  # Имя: Tom  Возраст: 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Отступы были не на 4 пробела, и комментарии `# устанавливаем имя` и `# устанавливаем возраст` пришлось убрать после всё заработало.